# Django: Displaying image from model field?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates

I'm having trouble getting an image to display. This should be really easy to fix. I'm just a noob. :/

My models.py is the following:

```
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Coin(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', verbose_name='image')
    website = models.URLField(max_length=200, default="https://example.com/")
    reddit = models.URLField(max_length=200, default="https://reddit.com/r/")
    twitter = models.URLField(max_length=200, default="https://twitter.com/")
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ticker

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


class CoinImage(models.Model):
    coin = models.ForeignKey(Coin, default=None, related_name='images',
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/uploads', verbose_name='image')
```

In my views.py I have:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
from django.template import loader
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Coin


def index(request):
    latest_coins_list = Coin.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_coins_list': latest_coins_list}
    return render(request, 'coins/index.html', context)

def detail(request, coin_id):
    try:
        coin = Coin.objects.get(pk=coin_id)
    except Coin.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Coin does not exist")
    return render(request, 'coins/detail.html', {'coin': coin})
```

My main urls.py is:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('coins/', include('coins.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

My app urls.py is:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:coin_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

Then finally in my template file details.html:

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{{ coin.logo.path }}" alt="La" />
<h1>{{ coin.name }} | {{ coin.ticker }}</h1>
<p>{{ coin.description }}</p>
<li><strong>Website:</strong> {{ coin.website }}</li>
<li><strong>Twitter:</strong> {{ coin.twitter }}</li>
<li><strong>Reddit:</strong> {{ coin.reddit }}</li>
```

When I view the template I get the alt text. Then when trying to access the image directly 127.0.0.1:8000/static/uploads/thumbs/me.jpg I get a template error saying:

> Page not found (404) Request Method:  GET Request URL:
>     http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/uploads/thumbs/me.jpg Raised by:
>     django.views.static.serve
>
> 'uploads/thumbs/me.jpg' could not be found
>
> You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django
>   settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a
>   standard 404 page.

This should be a really simple thing to do. If someone can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it so much. Sorry, am noob. :P

Added for someone:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'i*a%3!kg*mj7j-=5b@_3cx(^%sqr*&sp$-fg*qv=qewm!a-_gt'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'coins',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'blockintel.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'blockintel.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  '/static/')
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Comment: accesss the image with `{{ coin.logo.url }}`, but not sure this will be the only issue. add your `settings.MEDIA_URL` , `settings.MEDIA_ROOT` to your question.

Comment: I've set static_url and static_root. That's the same as media root right?

Comment: It's not about a bug, but rather something can be wrong, with your `upload_to` in the ImageField, show me this piece of code

Comment: statit_url or static_root has nothing to see with that

Comment: I've added settings.py to the OP.

Comment: logo = models.FileField(upload_to='static/uploads/thumbs')

I've tried ImageField too

Comment: ok! so you have three things that you did wrong, i'll post an answer

Comment: this is all running on my local dev environment too if you need to know that.

Answer (score 1):

During development, you can serve user-uploaded media files from `MEDIA_ROOT`. This is te absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files. in your settings, you should provide:

```
# MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'your_directory')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media') # media most of the time
```

[`MEDIA_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#media-url), URL that handles the media served from [`MEDIA_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#media-root), used for managing stored files. It must end in a slash if set to a non-empty value. You will need to configure these files to be served in both development and production environments. add this in your settings

```
# MEDIA_URL = '/your_url/'
MEIDA_URL = '/media/' # most of the time
```

You will need to do this as well by adding the following snippet to your root urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

> NOTE: This helper function works only in debug. [Know more here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development)

**ISSUES / SUGGESTIONS**

In this field, rather than uploading a file to `static` directory, just provide your media directory, in that case, it's `media`.

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', verbose_name='image')
```

Django will automatically create a directory: 'uploads' inside the `MEDIA_ROOT` which is `media`,

So access all your the images that you have with

```
# file.url 
{{ coin.logo.url }}
```

Comment: Now when I upload an image in admin and click it, it says "Coin with ID "1/change/media/uploads/Screenshot_from 18-05-05-54-55.png" doesn't exist. Perhaps it was deleted?"

Comment: this is also whats printing on the detail.html. still not displaying an image for some reason.

Comment: files, that you already uploaded don't have a correct path, so try uploading other files

Comment: NOTE: Files already on the platform before these settings configurations, will not be displayed, unless you change their paths manually.

Comment: I've tried reuploading files as well as adding new ones with the same result. :/ This is driving me nuts haha it should be so simple

Comment: if i do coin.logo.path i get an output: <img src="/home/noly/django-apps/blockintel/media/uploads/zen.png" alt="La">

but still no image displaying. is there something i need installed in my virtualenv or something? this is so weird.

Comment: Where exactly that you have the media directory, it should in your root project

Comment: yeah it is. /home/noly/django-apps/blockintel/ is my project root. so the location is showing correctly. there's just no image rendering in the browser.

Comment: `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'` slash before as after

Comment: BTW, remove these slashes `/` in your `STATIC_ROOT`, and you should provide [`STATICFILES_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS) as well to serve static files, js, css ...

Comment: Staticfiles_dirs should be full paths right? like for example the output above from coin.img.path? except for folders of course.

Comment: no! `STATICFILES_DIRS` should be like that: `STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')` where static is the directory of static files

Comment: You don't need `static_root` for development, it is a tool for production when you going to `collectstaticfiles` you provide it. And this directory must be different as `STATICFILES_DIRS`

Comment: I made a mistake in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50310995/5644965), I added `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'` with the slash before.  It's correct now